# Создание бесконечно повторяющегося метода в c#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

я занимаюсь разработкой приложения на Xamarin Forms и у меня возник следующий вопрос.
Как создать бесконечно повторяющийся метод в c#, который работает на протяжении работы приложения?
**Предположим**, я хочу создать метод, который должен через определенное количество времени выводить какую-то информацию на экран. Данный метод должен работать вне зависимости от действий пользователя.

Comment: Timer? Thread? ___

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Например с помощью [Асинхронного программирования](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

```cs
private async Task RunLoopAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // ... что-то сделать
            await Task.Delay(1000, token); // подождать одну секунду
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { } // сработала отмена, ничего не делать
}
```

Использовать

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

private async void StartLoop()
{
    if (_cts != null)
        return;
    try
    {
        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            await RunLoopAsync(_cts.Token);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ... ex.Message
    }
    _cts = null;
}

private void StopLoop()
{
    _cts?.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Реализация оказалась очень простой, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Изучаю и есть вопрос. Мне кто то писал тут, что не стоит создавать исключения лишний раз, так как это ресурсоёмкий процесс. А если я правильно понял, тут надо намеренно вызвать исключение чтобы выйти из цикла. Или для такого рода задач это норма ?

Comment: @Vipz здесь это норма. А потом, сколько миллионов раз в секунду вам надо отканселлить токен? :) А так, исключения - это очень быстро работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с Таймером

```
private bool isRunning = true;

#if !DEBUG
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), async() =>
{
    await MyFunctuonFromDBForUpdateDataAsync();

    return isRunning;
});
#endif
```

Comment: _где вы async void увидели ?_ - `async (_) =>` это `async void` лямбда, будьте внимательней. Это может затруднить отладку.