# Как правильно ставить паузы в методах, которые будут запускаться в Thread(метод)?

Tags: c#, async-await

Допустим есть метод:

```
public void WriteTo10sec()
{
    Console.WriteLine("begin");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Console.WriteLine("finish");
}
```

и этот метод запускается в создаваемых потоках 10 раз:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(WriteTo10sec);
    th.Start();
}
```

пишут, что Thread.Sleep - блокирует основной поток, и есть альтернатива Task.Delay, тогда
как правильно переписать метод WriteTo10sec, чтобы сохранялась пауза?
вариант:

```
public void WriteTo10sec()
{
    Console.WriteLine("begin");
    Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("finish");
}
```

делает задержку, но иногда гораздо больше, чем 10 сек и пишут, что Wait, так же блокирует основной поток - верно ли это?
можно ли задать точную паузу в методе WriteTo10sec без блокировки основного потока и не делая этот метод асинхронным, поскольку он запускается в отдельном Thread ?
т.е. не делая метод таким:

```
public async void WriteTo10sec()
{
    Console.WriteLine("begin");
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    Console.WriteLine("finish");
}
```

сейчас пробую оптимизировать код, в котором синхронный метод, который запускается в Thread, запускает в себе последовательно много других синхронных методов, в которых требуется соблюдать точные паузы. Можно ли обойтись без переписывания всего кода на асинхронный, если в конце концов метод вызывается асинхронно в Thread?

Comment: или в данном случае Thread.Sleep() блокирует только поток, в котором будет запущен метод, а не основной поток?

Comment: Почему бы вам это не выяснить опытным путем? :) Поставьте после цикла, где вы создаете и запускаете потоки, вывод в консоль. Если менее чем за 10 секунд вывод произойдет, то основной поток не будет заблокирован

Comment: `пишут, что Thread.Sleep - блокирует основной поток` - неправильно пишут. Правильно - блокирует текущий поток (см. документацию по методу [Thread.Sleep()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-5.0))

Comment: @Andrei Khotko, Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста! А вообще, если у вас методы внутри одного потока должны выполняться через одинаковые промежутки времени, используйте [System.Threading.Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019471/6468198)

Comment: Если вам нужна точная пауза, то `await Task.Delay` дает погрешность до 30мс в большую сторону. Используйте либо таймер, либо `Sleep` в потоке, второе наверное даже точнее. А если нужен правильный асинхронный пример, [то вот ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567), буквально вчера я писал ответ.