# Как остановить поток C#

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

У меня есть thread с циклом на 15 элементов и для эмитации работы я делаю sleep на секунду. Я сделала логику которая если юзер нажимает на кнопку повторно, то предыдущий поток должен быть остановлен и новый должен начать работу. Для этого я создала флаг `m_isShouldStop` и когда юзер повторно нажимает кнопку, то флаг меняется на `true` и следом вызываю `Wait` и ожидаю, что предыдущий поток остановиться, дождется `Wait`, создаст новый поток и начнет выполнение заново. Но происходит следующее - я вижу, что флаг меняется, но в потоке флаг как будто остается тем же(как будто работает с его копией) и `Wait` не выходит он просто зависает там.

Вот код:

```
 private Task m_exeTask;
 private static bool m_isShouldStop = false;
 private TaskFactory FactoryTask { get; set; }


 public void Start(int count)
        {
            if (m_exeTask != null)
            {
                m_isShouldStop = true;
                m_exeTask.Wait();
                m_exeTask.Dispose();
                m_exeTask = null;
                m_isShouldStop = false;
            }

            var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            m_exeTask = FactoryTask?.StartNew(() =>
            {
               if(m_isShouldStop ){
                      return;
                 }
                Console.WriteLine("HERE start the loop");

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                   Thread.Sleep(1000);    //WORK EMULATION
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                    //Here I do some UI stuff
                    Console.WriteLine("HERE start NEXT");
                    }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("HERE end the loop");

            }, tokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiContext);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Start(15);
        }
    }
```

Что делаю не так?

**ПРАВКА**
в итоге получилось так, код работает. Если есть рекомендации, пишите :-)

```
 CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public async void Start(int count)
        {
            if (m_exeTask != null)
            {
                cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
                await m_exeTask;
                m_exeTask.Dispose();
                m_exeTask = null;
                cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            }
            var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            m_exeTask = FactoryTask?.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HERE start the loop");

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (cancelTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("IT WAS CANCELED");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);    //WORK EMULATION
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            //Here I do some UI stuff
                            Console.WriteLine("HERE start NEXT");
                        }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("HERE end the loop");
            }, tokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiContext);
        }
```

Comment: Когда будете проверять флаг в потоке добавьте к нему [volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)

Comment: У вас в воркере нет проверки значения m_isShouldStop, поэтому он и продолжает выполняться.

Comment: К уже сказанному добавлю - не путайте потоки и Task-и, это не совсем одно и то же )

Comment: @Uranus извините, скопировала не тот кусочек, в моем коде эта проверка есть, отредактировала код, можете пожалуйста еще раз посмотреть.

Comment: @CrazyElf но на сколько я понимаю в моем случае не критично :-)

Comment: @Teti Ну как не критично. Для работы с `Task` есть свои шаблоны проектирования, которые сильно отличаются от того, как работали с потоками когда-то в древности :)

Comment: @Teti, теперь у вас проверка делается только один раз при старте воркера. Чтобы воркер завершал работу, он должен проверять время от времени.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot Вроде как получилось, добавила правку в вопрос, если есть рекомендации, буду рада услышать! спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `FactoryTask?.StartNew` заменить просто на `Task.Run`, он будет использовать правильный шедьюлер для выполнения на потоке из пула, так что его не надо будет задавать. `CancellationTokenSource` является `IDisposable`, ему надо высвобождать ресуры, нужен либо `using` либо `Dispose()`, посмотрите ссылку в моем ответе на пример. При использовании `async void` есть риск словить невидимое исключение, то есть оно уронит вам поток, но вы его не увидите, оберните код в `try-catch` и почитайте в статье по ссылке из ответа про асинхронность, чем опасен `async void`.

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }))` можно упростить как `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { })`. Кстати, про `async void` много всякого понаписано, поищите, почитайте, вам это пригодится.

Comment: `m_exeTask.Dispose();` - а вот это лишнее. Если вы не используете `Task.WaitHandle` явно (а вы не используете), то таск не нужно диспозить, хуже оно конечно не делает, но и лучше тоже.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Представьте себе ситуацию, когда вы вызвали `Wait()`, при этом поток еще продолжает выполняться. Сам `Wait()` уже заблокировал UI поток и он ждет.

Далее, в выполняемом потоке у вас вызывается `Dispatcher.Invoke`, то есть выполнение фрагмента кода в UI потоке, но он уже выполняет вот прямо сейчас `Wait()`, то есть заблокирован, при этом ваш поток ждет, когда `Dispatcher.Invoke` отработает, а `Dispatcher.Invoke` ждет, когда отработает `Wait()`, чтобы выполнить отправленный в него фрагмент кода.

И получается ситуация, когда UI поток ждет завершения сторого потока, а второй поток не может завершиться, пока UI поток не выполнит для него код. И вот они ждут друг друга...и ждут...и будут вечно ждать, пока вы не убьете приложение.

И такая смертельная для приложения взаимоблокировка потоков называется дэдлок - **Deadlock**.

Вылечить можно любым из способов:

1. Выполнить `Console.WriteLine()` прямо в потоке без вызова диспетчера
2. Вызвать диспетчер асинхронно, то есть `BeginInvoke` вместо `Invoke`, разница в том, что первый не будет ждать, пока отработает код в UI потоке
3. Ожидать завершения задачи асинхронно (не блокируя UI поток), то есть `await m_exeTask` вместо `m_exeTask.Wait()` - [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async)

---

Добавлю только что вместо `bool`, которая не является потокобезопасной, ибо может быть кеширована в потоке, надежнее использовать `volatile bool`, а еще лучше - познакомиться с тем, как используется `CancellationToken` ([вот пример его использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567)).

---

Так же проверку на выход стоит делать прямо в цикле

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (m_isShouldStop)
        return;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Да уж, лучше сразу `CancellationToken` использовать по прямому назначению, чем вот это вот всё )

Comment: @CrazyElf так написал же, и даже ссылку на пример воткнул :) Но использование CTS не освобождает от ответственности за неправильное ожидание завершения потока.

Comment: Да у меня не к вам претензия, просто в коде вопроса такого намешано... Прям на ностальгию пробивает, сам когда-то так писал, но это было очень давно ))