# С# как моментально остановить поток?

Tags: c#

Запускаю одновременно несколько тасков:

```
using (semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < MyCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        int id = i;
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();  
                    
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
              progress.Report("Автопостинг, канал : " + id);
        
              AddPost(progress, id, semaphore, false);
         }));

     }

     StatusWork = true;

      await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Метод `AddPost()` выглядит примерно вот так:

```
 public async void AddPost(IProgress<string> progress, int ChanelNubmer, SemaphoreSlim semaphore, bool IndividualStartCheck)
    {
        for (; ; )
        {
            // Полезная нагрузка 
            Task.Delay(200000);

            if (Stop == true)
            {
                progress.Report("Поток " + ChanelNubmer + " остановлен!");
                MyCollection[ChanelNubmer].Status = "Не работает";
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Метод выполняет определенную работу, затем ждет 200000 миллисекунд и повторяет действие заново.

Если нужно остановить работу метода - нажатием кнопки на форме я присваиваю логической переменной `Stop` значение `true`

Проблема в том что используя `Task.Delay(200000);`  - цикл будет остановлен не сразу.

Как в данном случае можно остановить работу метода моментально?

И метод `AddPost` я запускаю одновременно в нескольких потоках, если присвоить `Stop == true` - остановятся все потоки, можно как то обратиться к определенному потоку что бы остановить только его?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1257633/213987

Comment: `Task.Delay(200000);` вот здесь вы забыли про `await`. У вас приложение не виснет от запуска кучи `Delay` в секунду, случаем? Да и `semaphore.Release()` вы забыли вызывать при завершении операции.

Comment: aepot, Создаю 10 тасков с методом AddPost, приложение не виснет, я правильно понимаю что использую return - я останавливаю цикл for (; ; ),  а для того что бы убить таск - нужно использовать semaphore.Release() ?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `CancellationToken`.

`async void` нельзя ожидать, поэтому вся ваша конструкция с семафором не имела никакого смысла.

[Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async) - прочитайте обязательно.

```cs
public async Task AddPost(IProgress<string> progress, int channelNumber, SemaphoreSlim semaphore, bool individualStartCheck, CancellationToken token)
{
    progress.Report("Автопостинг, канал : " + channelNumber);
    try
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            // Полезная нагрузка 
            await Task.Delay(200000, token);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
    progress.Report("Поток " + channelNumber + " остановлен!");
    MyCollection[channelNumber].Status = "Не работает";
}
```

Далее объявите `CancellationTokenSource`

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
```

И вот так это использовать

```cs
if (_cts != null)
    return;

using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MyCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync(_cts.Token);  
                    
            tasks.Add(AddPost(progress, i, semaphore, false, _cts.Token));
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
_cts = null;
```

Чтобы всё остановить, просто вызовите

```cs
_cts?.Cancel();
```

При срабатывании отмены, асинхронные методы .NET бросают исключение `OperationCanceledException`, его нужно всего-лишь поймать. При желании вы так же внутри своих методов можете его бросить вот так:

```cs
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

Или без выбрасывания исключения делать проверку типа

```cs
if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    return;
```