# Как автоматически выполнять обновление lable на форме?

Tags: c#

У меня есть форма, на неё несколько lables они служат для индикации, когда программа работает, она считывает данные из базы данных, которые в свою очередь обновляются, и мне нужно чтобы эти lables тоже обновлялись, я хотел запустить Thread thread = new Thread(UpdateMeth); Но эта конструкция выдаёт ошибку "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" Подскажите как сделать так чтобы метод UpdateMeth() выполнялся постоянно?

```
Thread thread = new Thread(UpdateMeth);
thread.Start();
List<int> goldC { get; set; }
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateMeth();
}
private void UpdateMeth()
{
    goldC = baseTimerLogic.Check(userController.CurrentUser);
    lblPopulationCount.Content = goldC[0].ToString();
    lblFood.Content = goldC[1].ToString();
    lblRock.Content = goldC[2].ToString();
    lblWood.Content = goldC[3].ToString();
    lblIron.Content = goldC[4].ToString();
    lblCoal.Content = goldC[5].ToString();
    lblGold.Content = goldC[6].ToString();

}
```

Comment: Чтобы что-то обновлялось, нужен где-то цикл или таймер или что-то еще? При чем тут `Thread`? И код нужно писать в методах, а не в классе.

Comment: ну я думал, что thread можно запустить и он будет выполняться постоянно то есть выполнять UpdateMeth, который будет обновлять мой лейблы, а если сделать цикл бесконечный, то он просто зависнет навсегда)

Comment: Поток выполняет код, который вы ему дали. Он больше ничего не умеет делать. Вот готовый [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567). Копируете код в место где `// ... что-то сделать`, и делаете 2 кнопки "Старт" и "Стоп", из обработчика одной вызываете `StartLoop`, из другой `StopLoop`.

Comment: ... там где `// ... ex.Message` пишете `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)`, чтобы в случае чего увидеть ошибку, если возникнет.

Comment: `List<int> goldC` у вас объявлен как свойство, для чего? Уберите свойство и объявите список прямо там, где у вас код, в методе `List<int> goldC = ...`. В многопоточном и асинхронном программировании надо избегать использования глобальных переменных (полей и свойств) там, где возможно.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: РАБОТАЕЕЕЕТ..)) спасибо