# Асинхронность и Корутины в WinForms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, coroutine, ienumerator

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, в юнити для асинхронных действий есть очень удобный инструменты IEnumerator, для C# я нагуглил async, но не понял как этим пользоваться

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(someCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator someCcoroutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
}
```

Есть-ни что-то подобное в WinForms и как это использовать?
К примеру, мне нужно запустить таймер ожидания в отдельном потоке, чтобы потом в нем-же запустить некоторые действия. При этом основной поток должен продолжать свою стандартную работу

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а эти функции можно как-нибудь вызывать?

Comment: Зачем корутины в формах?

Comment: @tym32167, мне нужно вызвать дополнительный поток, в котором произойдет какое-то действие, через 3 секунды.  И во время ожидания этих 3х секунд выполнение основной программы не остановится. И таких задержек должно быть 10 для каждого отдельного объекта

Comment: Для этого не нужны корутины. Ожидайте асинхронно, вызывайте свои задачи через пул потоков.

Comment: @tym32167 Не мог-бы ты на примере показать, как это работает?

Comment: закинул пример ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример, как по нажатию кнопки подождать 3 секунды асинхронно и запустить какую то работу на пуле потоков

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        var button = new Button() { Text = "Press me!", Width = 200, Height = 50 };
        button.Click+=button_click;
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }
    
    private async void button_click(object sender, EventArgs args){
        await Task.Delay(3000); // ждем 3 секунды
        await Task.Run(() => {
            // Ваш код тут, 
            // только не пытайтесь работать с элементами формы 
            // из этого потока, не получится. 
            MessageBox.Show("boom!");
        });
    }
}
```

Результат

[image: ...]

Comment: Не знал, что MessageBox.Show можно вызывать не из гуи-потока...

Comment: @4per это же win32 api, там практически все функции потокобезопасны.

Comment: В методах типа `async void` стоит обрабатывать вероятные исключения, в противном случае разработчик их не увидит.

Comment: @aepot в данном случае исключение всплывет в ui поток, разве нет? Да и в любом случае, ответ явно не про обработку исключений.