# Прервать выполнение потока в WinForms

Tags: c#, многопоточность, .net-4.8

Есть приложение с нотификацией, которое отслеживает изменения в бд в реальном времени. Мне нужно чтобы но кнопке стоп поток приостанавливался, а по кнопке старт снова запускался. Я зашел в тупик, помогите пожалуйста. Сейчас по нажатию кнопки старт запускается еще +1 поток, а надо возобновлять остановленный(или что-то в этом роде). Как правильно остановить поток в коде, метод Abort работет через раз.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        private SqlConnection connection = null;
        private SqlCommand command = null;
        private const string ServiceName = "ChangeNotifications";
        private int NotificationTimeout = 600;
        public Thread listener;
        private int p = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
            "Initial Catalog=SQLNotificationRequestDB;Pooling=False;";
        }
        private string GetSQL()
        {
            return "SELECT id, flag, data from SQLNotificationRequestTable";
        }
        private string GetListenerSQL()
        {
            return "WAITFOR ( RECEIVE * FROM ChangeMessages);";
        }
        private void StartListener()
        {
                listener = new Thread(Listen);
                listener.Name = "Query Notification Watcher";
                listener.Start();

        }
        private void Listen()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection =
            new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand(GetListenerSQL(), connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.CommandTimeout = NotificationTimeout + 15;
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        messageText = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])reader.GetValue(13)).ToString();
                    }
                object[] args = { this, EventArgs.Empty };
                    EventHandler notify =
                    new EventHandler(OnNotificationComplete);
                    this.BeginInvoke(notify, args);
                    listener.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
        private string messageText;
        private void OnNotificationComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            messageText = messageText.Replace("??", "");
            label1.Text = messageText.Replace("\0", "");
            LoadData();
            GetData();
        }

        private void GetData()
        {
            command.Notification = null;
            SqlNotificationRequest snr =
            new SqlNotificationRequest();
            snr.UserData = new Guid().ToString();
            snr.Options = "Service=" + ServiceName;
            snr.Timeout = NotificationTimeout;
            command.Notification = snr;
            StartListener();
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            listener.Abort();
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadData();
            if (connection == null)
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            }
            if (command == null)
            {
                command = new SqlCommand(GetSQL(), connection);
            }
            if (button2.Enabled == true)
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
            GetData();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listener.Abort();
            connection.Close();
            p++;
                 if (button2.Enabled == true)
            {
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }

        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            string connectString = "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
            "Initial Catalog=SQLNotificationRequestDB;Pooling=False;";

            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectString);

            myConnection.Open();

            string query = "SELECT id, flag, data from SQLNotificationRequestTable";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                data.Add(new string[3]);

                data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
                data[data.Count - 1][2] = reader[2].ToString();
            }

            reader.Close();

            myConnection.Close();

            foreach (string[] s in data)
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо `listener.Abort();` достаточно просто написать `return;`, завершение выполнения метода здесь приравнивается к выходу из потока. Или даже вообще просто убрать эту строчку, так как дальше кода нет. Метод и так завершится.

Как это работает:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(Method);
    thread.Start();
    Console.WriteLine(thread.IsAlive);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(thread.IsAlive);
}

static void Method()
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
True
False
```

То есть поток автоматически завершается как только код, который был запущен в этом потоке, завершает работу.

Еще советую никогда не использовать `Thread.Abort()`, так как это может привести к нестабильности приложения.

`Abort()` не гарантирует завершение потока. Вот пример, как это воспроизвести, данный поток невозоможно завершить. Так же, так как он не является фоновым, приложение так же невозможно завершить. То есть единственый способ завершения - это принудительно остановить отладку или закрыть окно консоли, а если Winforms, то и вовсе придется убивать процесс через Диспетчер задач. Не используйте `Abort()`.

```
// ПЛОХОЙ КОД, НЕ ДЕЛАЙТЕ ТАК!
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(Method);
    thread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    thread.Abort(); // не работает
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(thread.IsAlive);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

static void Method()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    finally
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

То есть все что вам надо сделать - это завершить запущенный в потоке код. Обратите внимание на бесконечную рекурсию `StartListener()` -> `Listen()` -> `OnNotificationComplete()` -> `GetData()` -> `StartListener()` -> `Listen()` -> `...и далее по кругу до бесконечности`, вам нужно разорвать это кольцо. Вызывая `Abort()` вы останавливаете только один поток, но на тот момент у вас уже запущена большая куча таких потоков, а в переменной сохранен только последний. Это работает как цепная реакция `Thread1` -> `UI` -> `Thread2` -> `UI` -> `Thread3` -> `UI` -> ..., и каждый раз при перезапуске `StartListener`, он перезаписывает переменную `listener`, теряя связь с тем потоком, ссылка на который там хранилась.

Посмотрите этот пример:

- [Создание бесконечно повторяющегося метода в c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1257309/373567)