# Почему код не останавливается на await?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

```
Thread ThreadWindow = new Thread(async () =>
{
    WindowWPF windowWPF = new WindowWPF();
    windowWPF.Show();
    
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //всякий код
        }
    });
    
    //код который не должен работать а он работает =\
});
```

Так же компилятор мне почему-то предлагает изменить последнию строку:
}); в }){}; к чему это?

Идея вывести окно с загрузкой и параллельно работать с данными после чего окно должно закрыться.

Comment: Что значит «не останавливается на await»?

Comment: а почему он должен работать? вы же используете await, что переводится как "ожидать". а у вас там бесконечный цикл

Comment: @return В моём понятии пока цикл не кончится, он не пойдет дальше, а почему-то получается и цикл работает и код после цикла

Comment: 'В моём понятии' потому что код АСИНХРОННЫЙ и при написанний кода это нужно учитовать

Comment: @СергейШашко сам поток асинхронен ThreadWindow для наружнего кода, разве нет? почему же await не срабатывает(

Comment: А внутри там не `async () =>` тоже должна быть лямбда? И у вас компилятор по идее должен же ругаться, если у вас там нигде `await` нету внутри `Task.Run`. Или он есть?

Comment: На этот вопрос невозмножно ответить не зная, что такое "всякий код". И очень страшно у вас  тут намешано. Хотя-бы начать с того что вы не можете открыть окно из рабочего потока, и я вообще не уверен что дело до `await` в принципе доходит.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567 пример асинхронного цикла, никаких Task.Run или Thread не требуется.

Comment: @aepot под "всякий код" можно ничего не писать, там просто "console.log". А вот using мне нужно будет почитать, спасибо.

Comment: @CrazyElf внутри Task.Run нету и не нужен await

Comment: Не воспроизводится, взял ваш код за исключением обертки из Thread, запустил, работает как надо.