# Как возобновить цикл через CancellationToken?

Tags: c#

У меня в начале формы инициализируются cancellationtokensource cts = new cancellationtokensource();
и cancellationtoken ct = cts.Token;

есть кнопка, останавливающая цикл,
в ней я прописал cts.Cancel()
. а в цикле, который находится в обработчике события второй кнопки и await Task.Run(() я прописал if(ct.IsCancellationTokenRequested){break;}
но, когда я нажимаю на запустить, а затем на остановить, цикл останавливается, но если опять нажать запустить, то цикл заново не запускается

Comment: cancellationtokensource может отменяться только один раз, после отмены оно остаётся в таком состоянии. Вам нужно на каждый запуск задачи создавать новый cancellationtokensource.

Comment: тоесть на кнопку запустить я должен прописать еще и cancellationtokensource cts = new cancellationtokensource(); и cancellationtoken ct = cts.Token;?

Comment: Именно. Плюс cancellationtokensource нужно в конце выполнения диспоузить и там ещё есть приколы с синхронизации потоков, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: в конце это после cancel()?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567