# Как менять цвет фона WF раз в секунду n раз в c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Кнопка button1 нажимается 1 раз, вместо 10(заложено через цикл for).

Неоходимо организовать смену цвета фона WF раз в секунду 10 раз.

````
namespace WfChangeColor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();       
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                button1.PerformClick(); //нажатие кнопки 10 раз???
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            changeFormColor(); //меняет цвет через секунду
        }

        public void changeFormColor()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Random random = new Random();
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(256), random.Next(256), random.Next(256));
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sleep` использовать не надо, он будет блокировать UI поток, вместо него нужен таймер. В конструкторе заводите его:

```
var timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Start();
```

Интервал поставите тот, который нужен вам.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // тут ваш код по смене цвета
    Random random = new Random();
    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(256), random.Next(256), random.Next(256));
}
```

Зачем нажимать кнопку 10 раз я не знаю, но таймер можно запускать по нажатию кнопки в `button1_Click`, если надо.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! С таймером все сразу заработало. Сейчас изучу что и как.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без таймера обойтись. С минимальными изменениями в вашем коде:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                button1.PerformClick();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeFormColor();
        }

        private void ChangeFormColor()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(255), random.Next(255), random.Next(255));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю, Алексей!