# Не работает кнопка в winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Проблема заключается в том что я переношу один код(который работает на другой кнопке) на другую кнопку, но при нажатии на неё ничего не происходит

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SoundPlayer Simple = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\danya\Downloads\krik.wav");
        Simple.Play();
        label1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = false;
        button1.Visible = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            await Task.Delay(70);
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
            await Task.Delay(70);
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Эта новая кнопка связана с обработчиком нажатия или вы просто эту функцию копируете и ждёте, что она сама заработает?

Comment: Откройте дизайнер формы и проверьте, задан ли обработчик событию Click.

Comment: По поводу самого кода, загляните [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567), быть может интересно.

Comment: @aepot благодарю за помощь, я новичок и не знал про обработчик событий, всё работает