# Как правильно разработать "Интерполяцию" движения в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, tcp, асинхронность

Сервер обрабатывает каждого игрока, в случаи его движения, всем отправляет конечную точку направления и текущее направления с учетом скорости. Не как не получается синхронизировать движение. На клиенте частые подергивания, из-за того, что на сервере игрок отстает от клиента. И при дистанции больше чем в 2f телепортирует его на серверные координаты. Пробовал таймер ставить на 500 мл/с, но тогда уже клиент телепортирует его вперед, что на стороне клиента не успевает его двигать. А подбирать значение как-то костыльно я так думаю. Пожалуйста, киньте кто пример простейший, на стороне клиента и сервера как правильно интерполяцию можно сделать. Движок unity, протокол транспортировки tcp. Заранее спасибо.

```
namespace KOBServer.Models.Base
{
    public sealed class CharacterMovement
    {
        public CharacterMovement(NetCharacter character)
        {
            _character = character;
            IsMoving = false;
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            _timer.Elapsed += MovedElapsed;
        }

        private readonly NetCharacter _character;

        public bool IsMoving { get; private set; }

        private float DestinationX = 0;
        private float DestinationY = 0;
        private float DestinationZ = 0;
        private float PositionX { get => _character.PositionX; set => _character.PositionX = value; }
        private float PositionY { get => _character.PositionY; set => _character.PositionY = value; }
        private float PositionZ { get => _character.PositionZ; set => _character.PositionZ = value; }

        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        private void PerformMove()
        {
            if (!IsMoving)
                return;

            float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(DestinationX - PositionX, 2) +
                Math.Pow(DestinationY - PositionY, 2) + Math.Pow(DestinationZ - PositionZ, 2));

            float vectorDirectionX = ((DestinationX - PositionX) / distance) * _character._characterStats.MoveSpeed;
            float vectorDirectionY = ((DestinationY - PositionY) / distance) * _character._characterStats.MoveSpeed;
            float vectorDirectionZ = ((DestinationZ - PositionZ) / distance) * _character._characterStats.MoveSpeed;

            if (distance < _character._characterTemplate.AttackDistance)
            {
                NotifyStopMove();
                return;
            }

            if (!_character.IsBot)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{new string('-', 100)}\n[server] debug: distance: {distance}");
                Console.WriteLine($"[server] message: added vector tick: x:{vectorDirectionX} y:{vectorDirectionY} z:{vectorDirectionZ}");
                Console.WriteLine($"{new string('-', 100)}");
            }

            PositionX += vectorDirectionX;
            PositionY += vectorDirectionY;
            PositionZ += vectorDirectionZ;
        }

        private async void MovedElapsed(object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            PerformMove();

            await _character.SendPacketAsync(CharacterUpdatePosition.ToPacket(_character));
            await _character.BroadcastPacketAsync(BroadcastCharacterPosition.ToPacket(_character));
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public void UpdatePosition(float x, float y, float z)
        {
            if (!IsMoving)
                _timer.Enabled = true;

            IsMoving = true;

            DestinationX = x;
            DestinationY = y;
            DestinationZ = z;
        }

        private void NotifyStopMove()
        {
            IsMoving = false;
            _timer.Enabled = false;
            _timer.Stop();
        }

        public void ClearMovement()
        {
            if (IsMoving)
                _timer.Stop();

            _timer.Elapsed -= MovedElapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _протокол транспортировки tcp_ - не делаются клиентские реалтайм игры на TCP уже давно из-за HoL задержек, такие игры делаются на UDP. TCP подойдет для игр типа шахмат разве что. Кстати, раз уж вы умеете await, то зачем `Timer`? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567 А по поводу клиентского предсказания, просто физика должна быть реализована на сервере одинаково как на клиенте, плюс учитывать во всей математике jitter - лаг между клиентом и сервером (половина пинга), иначе точного предсказания не получится. То есть это не просто интерполяция, а полное повторение вычислений.

Comment: Кстати, `async void` зло. По куче причин. Судя по тому что не обрабатываете в нем исключения, вы не в курсе, что это зло. Советую поизучать, материалов на эту тему много.

Comment: Не какая физика не учитывается на клиенте. vector3.movetowards использую для движени и расчет дистанции между реальными координатами позиции сервера и клиентскими. Пример синхронизации бы...