# Как остановить бесконечный цикл?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Есть телеграмм-бот, у него есть команда, которая выполняется бесконечно, пока не придет апдейт с командой "/stop".

```
public override async void Execute(String command, Message message, ITelegramBotClient client, State state)
{
   
    if (message.Text == "/stop")
        StopLoop();
    
    if(message.Text == "/start")
        StartLoop(message,client);

}
   
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
private async Task RunLoopAsync(CancellationToken token,Message message, ITelegramBotClient client )
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await client.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "send", cancellationToken: token);
            await Task.Delay(10000, token); 
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { } 
}
private async void StartLoop(Message message, ITelegramBotClient client)
{
    if (_cts != null)
        return;
    try
    {
        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            await RunLoopAsync(_cts.Token,message,client);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ... ex.Message
    }
    _cts = null;
}

private void StopLoop()
{
    _cts?.Cancel();
}
```

Для остановки цикла, я взял пример отсюда: [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1257309/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-c)

Но это не помогает. Что посоветуете сделать, чтобы можно было остановить этот цикл?

Comment: Код выглядит нормально. Используйте отладку и логирование. Либо вы не всё показали.

Comment: @aepot Это весь код, который есть в этой команде. В `if (message.Text == "/stop") StopLoop();` код доходит, после чего оно присылает сообщение :"end"(я добавил туда CW, чтобы это увидеть + откладка). Меня смутило только то, что _cts.IsCancellationRequested остается false.

Comment: Ещё учтите, что этот код может обслуживать только одного клиента. Поле _cts не может быть использовано многократно. Вам понадобится что-то вроде словаря, который в качестве ключа использует id пользователя, а в качестве значения cts.

Comment: @aepot У меня уже реализован конечный автомат для других нужд. И тут, я так понял, его тоже нужно использовать?

Comment: Ну да, здесь что-то типа `ConcurrentDictionary` для хранения `cts` подойдёт. Но для одного единственного пользователя то что вы показали,должно работать нормально.

Comment: @aepot Пожалуй, тогда это и есть ответ для меня. Напишите ваш ответ, чтобы я отметил. Благодарю вас.

Comment: Лучше вы сами, когда разберётесь. Я не знаю, что именно писать, это были лишь догадки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @aepot за догадки, ибо они помогли. Для успешного окончания цикла, у меня в коде нужно добавить конечный автомат:

```
public override async void Execute(String command, Message message, ITelegramBotClient client, State state)
{
    state.ActionCommand = "/start";
    var searchState = await _context.SearchState.FindAsync((e => e.UserId == message.Chat.Id))
        .Result.FirstOrDefaultAsync()??new SearchState(){_cts = new CancellationTokenSource()};
    _cts = searchState._cts;
    
    if (message.Text == "/stop")
    {
        searchState.IsWork = "false";
        await _stateMachine.DeleteState(message.Chat.Id);
        await _context.SearchState.ReplaceOneAsync((f=>f.UserId == message.Chat.Id),searchState);
        await client.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "end");
        StopLoop();
    }

    if (message.Text == "/start")
    {
        searchState.UserId = message.Chat.Id;
        searchState.IsWork = "true";
        await _context.SearchState.InsertOneAsync(searchState);
        StartLoop(message, client);

    }
}

private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
private async Task RunLoopAsync(CancellationToken token,Message message, ITelegramBotClient client )
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var find = await _context.SearchState.FindAsync((e => e.UserId == message.Chat.Id)).Result.FirstOrDefaultAsync()??new SearchState();
            if (find.IsWork == "false")
            {
                await _context.SearchState.DeleteOneAsync(f => f.UserId == message.Chat.Id);
                return;
            }

            await _parserWorker.Work(message, client, message.Chat.Id);
            await Task.Delay(120000, token); 
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { } 
}
private async void StartLoop(Message message, ITelegramBotClient client)
{

    try
    {
        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            await RunLoopAsync(_cts.Token,message,client);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ... ex.Message
    }
    _cts = null;
}

private void StopLoop()
{
    _cts?.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: `_cts` тоже нужно унести в state. Подумайте еще хорошенько. Что будет, если у одного юзера уже всё выполняется, в другой выполнил эту же команду

Comment: @aepot Посмотрел, что будет. Если не добавить в state _cts, то бот перестанет отвечать.

Comment: Я ее вижу ваш код целиком и не имею времени долго в нем разбираться. Вам виднее, как лучше сделать. Я лишь указал на проблему.