# Хорошая ли идея запускать бесконечные асинхронные методы?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Есть некий класс с парсером поисковой системы.

```csarp
public class Duckduckgo
{
     public async Task GetSnippetHttpClientAsync(CancellationToken token, SQLiteKeyRepository repository, int timeout, int pause)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

            var result = await ParseHttpAsync(repository, token, timeout, pause);
        }

    }

     private async Task<string> ParseHttpAsync(SQLiteKeyRepository repository, CancellationToken token, int timeout, int pause)
    {

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
          //тут логика парсера, если что то случается то проццес начинается с начала.
        }
        return null;

    }



}
```

Запуск происходит вот так

```csarp
 for (int i = 0; i < parseduckhttp; i++)
    {
     Duckduckgo h = new Duckduckgo();
     h.GetSnippetHttpClientAsync(token, repositoryKey, timeouthttp, pausehttp);                           
    }
```

Методы выполняются пока я не сделаю `cancelTokenSource.Cancel();`
И вот вопрос это вообще нормально выполнять такие теоретический бесконечные методы?
Можно было конечно для каждой задачи создавать свой объект и в нем 1 раз запускать метод, но я подумал что это сильно скажется на производительности, ведь объектов может быть и 300 чаще всего выполнение метода будет заканчиваться ошибкой и бОльшая часть времени будет уходить на создание новых объектов а не на полезную работу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567 не нужно проверять IsCancellationRequested в цикле, нужно чтобы используемый асинхронный метод это проверял. А так, на этот вопрос объективно ответить сложно. Если надо запускать что-то постоянно - запускайте, никто не против. Ошибка у вас только одна - где `await` здесь `h.GetSnippetHttpClientAsync`. Метод возвращает `Task` и вы его теряете. Создайте список тасок, потом `await Task.WhenAll` ему сделаете, чтобы дождаться завершения работы после отмены токена. Иначе возникшие необработанные исключения уйдут в бездну, и вы не узнаете об ошибках.

Comment: Вызов асинхронного метода без `await` это равносильно `async void` - то есть ничего хорошего. Вот еще примеры https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567

Comment: @aepot асинхронная пустота - нет ничего более поэтичного