# Программное нажатие клавиш в игре

Tags: c#, directx

Моя цель : Написать программу которая будет выполнять определенные действия в игре (В данном примере нажатие клавиши клавиатуры) когда происходит какое либо событие.

Я остановился на моменте с нажатием клавиш. Пробовал много вариантов и нашел подходящий, но он работает некорректно в моем случае.

```
public class Keyboard
{
    [Flags]
    public enum InputType
    {
        Mouse = 0,
        Keyboard = 1,
        Hardware = 2
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum KeyEventF
    {
        KeyDown = 0x0000,
        ExtendedKey = 0x0001,
        KeyUp = 0x0002,
        Unicode = 0x0004,
        Scancode = 0x0008,
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, Input[] pInputs, int cbSize);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();

    public enum DirectXKeyStrokes
    {
        DIK_ESCAPE = 0x01,
        DIK_1 = 0x02,
        DIK_2 = 0x03,
        DIK_3 = 0x04,
        DIK_4 = 0x05,
        DIK_5 = 0x06,
        DIK_6 = 0x07,
        DIK_7 = 0x08,
        DIK_8 = 0x09,
        DIK_9 = 0x0A,
        DIK_0 = 0x0B,
        DIK_MINUS = 0x0C,
        DIK_EQUALS = 0x0D,
        DIK_BACK = 0x0E,
        DIK_TAB = 0x0F,
        DIK_Q = 0x10,
        DIK_W = 0x11,
        DIK_E = 0x12,
        DIK_R = 0x13,
        DIK_T = 0x14,
        DIK_Y = 0x15,
        DIK_U = 0x16,
        DIK_I = 0x17,
        DIK_O = 0x18,
        DIK_P = 0x19,
        DIK_LBRACKET = 0x1A,
        DIK_RBRACKET = 0x1B,
        DIK_RETURN = 0x1C,
        DIK_LCONTROL = 0x1D,
        DIK_A = 0x1E,
        DIK_S = 0x1F,
        DIK_D = 0x20,
        DIK_F = 0x21,
        DIK_G = 0x22,
        DIK_H = 0x23,
        DIK_J = 0x24,
        DIK_K = 0x25,
        DIK_L = 0x26,
        DIK_SEMICOLON = 0x27,
        DIK_APOSTROPHE = 0x28,
        DIK_GRAVE = 0x29,
        DIK_LSHIFT = 0x2A,
        DIK_BACKSLASH = 0x2B,
        DIK_Z = 0x2C,
        DIK_X = 0x2D,
        DIK_C = 0x2E,
        DIK_V = 0x2F,
        DIK_B = 0x30,
        DIK_N = 0x31,
        DIK_M = 0x32,
        DIK_COMMA = 0x33,
        DIK_PERIOD = 0x34,
        DIK_SLASH = 0x35,
        DIK_RSHIFT = 0x36,
        DIK_MULTIPLY = 0x37,
        DIK_LMENU = 0x38,
        DIK_SPACE = 0x39,
        DIK_CAPITAL = 0x3A,
        DIK_F1 = 0x3B,
        DIK_F2 = 0x3C,
        DIK_F3 = 0x3D,
        DIK_F4 = 0x3E,
        DIK_F5 = 0x3F,
        DIK_F6 = 0x40,
        DIK_F7 = 0x41,
        DIK_F8 = 0x42,
        DIK_F9 = 0x43,
        DIK_F10 = 0x44,
        DIK_NUMLOCK = 0x45,
        DIK_SCROLL = 0x46,
        DIK_NUMPAD7 = 0x47,
        DIK_NUMPAD8 = 0x48,
        DIK_NUMPAD9 = 0x49,
        DIK_SUBTRACT = 0x4A,
        DIK_NUMPAD4 = 0x4B,
        DIK_NUMPAD5 = 0x4C,
        DIK_NUMPAD6 = 0x4D,
        DIK_ADD = 0x4E,
        DIK_NUMPAD1 = 0x4F,
        DIK_NUMPAD2 = 0x50,
        DIK_NUMPAD3 = 0x51,
        DIK_NUMPAD0 = 0x52,
        DIK_DECIMAL = 0x53,
        DIK_F11 = 0x57,
        DIK_F12 = 0x58,
        DIK_F13 = 0x64,
        DIK_F14 = 0x65,
        DIK_F15 = 0x66,
        DIK_KANA = 0x70,
        DIK_CONVERT = 0x79,
        DIK_NOCONVERT = 0x7B,
        DIK_YEN = 0x7D,
        DIK_NUMPADEQUALS = 0x8D,
        DIK_CIRCUMFLEX = 0x90,
        DIK_AT = 0x91,
        DIK_COLON = 0x92,
        DIK_UNDERLINE = 0x93,
        DIK_KANJI = 0x94,
        DIK_STOP = 0x95,
        DIK_AX = 0x96,
        DIK_UNLABELED = 0x97,
        DIK_NUMPADENTER = 0x9C,
        DIK_RCONTROL = 0x9D,
        DIK_NUMPADCOMMA = 0xB3,
        DIK_DIVIDE = 0xB5,
        DIK_SYSRQ = 0xB7,
        DIK_RMENU = 0xB8,
        DIK_HOME = 0xC7,
        DIK_UP = 0xC8,
        DIK_PRIOR = 0xC9,
        DIK_LEFT = 0xCB,
        DIK_RIGHT = 0xCD,
        DIK_END = 0xCF,
        DIK_DOWN = 0xD0,
        DIK_NEXT = 0xD1,
        DIK_INSERT = 0xD2,
        DIK_DELETE = 0xD3,
        DIK_LWIN = 0xDB,
        DIK_RWIN = 0xDC,
        DIK_APPS = 0xDD,
        DIK_BACKSPACE = DIK_BACK,
        DIK_NUMPADSTAR = DIK_MULTIPLY,
        DIK_LALT = DIK_LMENU,
        DIK_CAPSLOCK = DIK_CAPITAL,
        DIK_NUMPADMINUS = DIK_SUBTRACT,
        DIK_NUMPADPLUS = DIK_ADD,
        DIK_NUMPADPERIOD = DIK_DECIMAL,
        DIK_NUMPADSLASH = DIK_DIVIDE,
        DIK_RALT = DIK_RMENU,
        DIK_UPARROW = DIK_UP,
        DIK_PGUP = DIK_PRIOR,
        DIK_LEFTARROW = DIK_LEFT,
        DIK_RIGHTARROW = DIK_RIGHT,
        DIK_DOWNARROW = DIK_DOWN,
        DIK_PGDN = DIK_NEXT,
        
        DIK_LEFTMOUSEBUTTON = 0x100,
        DIK_RIGHTMOUSEBUTTON  = 0x101,
        DIK_MIDDLEWHEELBUTTON = 0x102,
        DIK_MOUSEBUTTON3 = 0x103,
        DIK_MOUSEBUTTON4 = 0x104,
        DIK_MOUSEBUTTON5 = 0x105,
        DIK_MOUSEBUTTON6 = 0x106,
        DIK_MOUSEBUTTON7 = 0x107,
        DIK_MOUSEWHEELUP = 0x108,
        DIK_MOUSEWHEELDOWN = 0x109,
    }
    
    public static void SendKey(DirectXKeyStrokes key, bool keyUp, InputType inputType)
    {
        var flagToSend = keyUp
            ? (uint)(KeyEventF.KeyUp | KeyEventF.Scancode)
            : (uint)(KeyEventF.KeyDown | KeyEventF.Scancode);

        Input[] inputs =
        {
            new()
            {
                Type = (int) inputType,
                U = new InputUnion
                {
                    ki = new KeyboardInput
                    {
                        wVk = 0,
                        wScan = (ushort) key,
                        dwFlags = flagToSend,
                        dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo()
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        SendInput((uint) inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Input)));
    }
    
    public static void SendKey(ushort key, bool keyUp, InputType inputType)
    {
        var flagToSend = keyUp
            ? (uint)(KeyEventF.KeyUp | KeyEventF.Scancode)
            : (uint)(KeyEventF.KeyDown | KeyEventF.Scancode);

        Input[] inputs =
        {
            new()
            {
                Type = (int) inputType,
                U = new InputUnion
                {
                    ki = new KeyboardInput
                    {
                        wVk = 0,
                        wScan = key,
                        dwFlags = flagToSend,
                        dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo()
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        SendInput((uint) inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Input)));
    }

    public struct Input
    {
        public int Type;
        public InputUnion U;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct InputUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public readonly MouseInput mi;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public KeyboardInput ki;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public readonly HardwareInput hi;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MouseInput
    {
        public readonly int dx;
        public readonly int dy;
        public readonly uint mouseData;
        public readonly uint dwFlags;
        public readonly uint time;
        public readonly IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct KeyboardInput
    {
        public ushort wVk;
        public ushort wScan;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public readonly uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct HardwareInput
    {
        public readonly uint uMsg;
        public readonly ushort wParamL;
        public readonly ushort wParamH;
    }
}
```

Проблема тут такая, что при выполнении программы и выполнении подходящих условий кнопка не нажимается, она срабатывает только тогда когда я нажимаю любую кнопку на клавиатуре.

Например :

```
while (true)
{
    // мой код

    Keyboard.SendKey(Keyboard.DirectXKeyStrokes.DIK_1, true, Keyboard.InputType.Keyboard);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Keyboard.SendKey(Keyboard.DirectXKeyStrokes.DIK_1, false, Keyboard.InputType.Keyboard);

    // мой код
}
```

Тут должна нажаться кнопку "1" на клавиатуре, но она нажимается 2 раза (1 раз за проход цикла) только тогда, когда я нажму например кнопку "L" (или любую другую) на клавиатуре.

Я что-то делаю не так? Может вы можете предложить что-нибудь получше?

Игра работает на DirectX.

Comment: Между отправкой нажатия и отпускания нужно асинзронное ожидание, а не заморозка потока, `await Task.Delay(100)` в `async` методе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567

Comment: `DirectXKeyStrokes` это вообще откуда перечисление? Вы его сами сюда прикрутили или так и было? Вообще в игре на базе DirectX такие нажатия в принципе могут не работать, если она работает с драйвером клавиатуры напрямую, это нормально.

Comment: @aepot, ```DirectXKeyStrokes``` я нашел тут : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138778/sending-keys-to-a-directx-game#72288515, нажатия работают и игра реагирует на них, но это происходит только после того как я нажму любую кнопку на клавиатуре.

Comment: Понятно, ну ответы выше над вопросом. Только вы не сказали, какой тип приложения, винформы или wpf. Но я думаю, разберётесь.