Minimal Api как затормозить поток запросов?
В c# я не сильно давно, можно сказать, только познаю его. Однако, пытаюсь кой-чего реализовать в коде и возник один вопрос.
Использую Minimal Api. Это там, где app.MapGet() и вот это вот всё.
ну вроде такого:
app.MapGet("/stubs/handler_api.php", async (HttpRequest request, ActionHandler actionHandler) =>
{
    return await actionHandler.DoAction(request);
});

Внутри DoAction есть ветвление, в зависимости от разобранного запроса он может быть отправлен к местную базу данных на MariaDB (11.4), либо может быть переадресован на другой сервис через http post запрос.
Перед тем как выполнить этот http запрос в другой сервис, я его предварительно "форматирую" согласно требований самого сервиса. Проблема возникает в тот момент, когда на наш сервис идёт большой наплыв запросов. скажем, 100 в секунду. Вроде не много, но для второго сервиса (он не наш) это много и они просят соблюдать рекомендованные паузы, которые они отправляют ответом. Я получаю эту паузу из их ответа, но, не очень понял, что делать с ней дальше.
Попробовал сделать так:
private Logger logger;
private List<UserLimit> userLimitList;
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
private readonly System.Timers.Timer cleanupTimer;

private readonly TimeSpan inactiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

public LimitsHandler(Logger logger)
{
    this.logger = logger;
    userLimitList = new List<UserLimit>();

    cleanupTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);   // Проверять каждую секунду
    cleanupTimer.Elapsed += DecrementLimitTimer;
    cleanupTimer.Start();
}

public async Task SetLimit(int countryId, string serviceId, int limitTime)
{
    try
    {
        if (await semaphore.WaitAsync(2000))
        {
            var limit = userLimitList
                .Where(ul => ul.CountryId == countryId && ul.ServiceId == serviceId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (limit == null)
            {
                userLimitList.Add(new UserLimit()
                {
                    CountryId = countryId,
                    ServiceId = serviceId,
                    LimitTime = limitTime + 1
                });
            }
            else
            {
                limit.LimitTime = limitTime + 1;    // Обновление счетчика
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error($"[SetUserLimit] Failed to lock the resource for update. {ex.ToString()}");
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}

public async Task<bool> GetLimit(int countryId, string serviceId)
{
    bool isLockAcquired = false;

    try
    {
        isLockAcquired = await semaphore.WaitAsync(2000);
        if (isLockAcquired)
        {
            var limitExists = userLimitList
                .Any(ul => ul.CountryId == countryId && ul.ServiceId == serviceId);
            return limitExists;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error($"[GetLimit] Failed to lock the resource for update. {ex}");
        return true; // true - значит лимит присутствует
    }
    finally
    {
        if (isLockAcquired) // Освобождаем семафор только если он был успешно захвачен
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    logger.Error("[GetLimit] Could not acquire the semaphore in the allotted time.");
    return true; // true - значит лимит присутствует
}

private void DecrementLimitTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (userLimitList)
    {
        for (int i = userLimitList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var limit = userLimitList[i];
            limit.LimitTime--;

            // Проверяем, если LimitTime достиг 0
            if (limit.LimitTime <= 0)
            {
                logger.Info($"[DecrementLimitTimer] Removing limit for CountryId: {limit.CountryId}, ServiceId: {limit.ServiceId}");
                userLimitList.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

При входе в DoAction выполняется вызов GetLimits. При первом входе там пусто и запрос свободно пролетает на второй сервис. от туда я ловлю лимит и выставляю там же вызывая SetLimit(). При повторном обращении в рамках этого временного лимита всё ок, юзер ловит паузу. Но, когда она проходит, то снова вся пачка запросов летит на второй сервис. Т.е. иными словами, запросы от юзеров ходят пачками, а мне бы их как то разделить во времени, чтобы они в итоге на второй сервис заходили чуть чуть друг за другом. Попытка воткнуть внутри GetLimit() семафоры результата не дали, так же как и Lock() (с ним вообще тормоза начались).
Да, чуть не забыл.  ActionHandler и класс содержащий DoAction в контейнере зарегистрированы как Scoped. Вот даже есть мысль, что DoAction должен быт ь как Singleton и на входе поставить семафора? не уверен.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567 вдруг в тему как пример

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567 советую избавиться от таймера, теряете в нём контекст синхронизации

@aepot .Net 6.0
Таймер чем можно заменить?

@aepot, по первой ссылке, видел её, да. но не понял как такое у себя применить. Обработчик роута синглтоном делать?

При наличии такой завязки на сторонний сервис, его ограничения по частоте запросов и рекомендуемые паузы становятся вашими. Соответсвенно вам необходимо информировать об этом своих клиентов и производить отаказ в обслуживании при превышении.

@user7860670, не можем. мы используем одно документированное апи, по которому уже регламентированы ответы. мы не можем своим юзерам выдавать ответы от второго сервиса и регламентировать им выполнять паузы. это ложится на наши плечи. Более того, если прилетает большая пачка запросов "одновременно" от каких то юзеров, мы её перенаправляем дальше. именно это вызывает проблему на втором сервисе. и чем чаще такое происходит , тем больше становится время ожидание, вплоть для блокировки нашего ключа. и юзерам не объяснить, что "ваши 100 потоков кладут всё". они просто уйдут туда. где не кладут.

"просто уйдут туда. где не кладут" - такое развите событий вполне вероятно

Таймер чем можно заменить? - серьёзно? Дал же ссылку в том же сообщении, чем.

Кешируйте данные, ограничивайте работу с внешним сервисом по его правилам, масштабируйте сервис. Например используйте несколько учётных записей/несколько IP адресов для доступа к внешнему сервису, чтобы увеличить пропускную способность. Создавайте свои правила и ограничения, это нормально. HTTP 429 Too Many Requests, HTTP заголовок "Retry-After" и т.д. Чтобы что-то реализовать, нужно разобраться, что нужно и какие есть возможности, а не идти вечно "в лоб".

"Кешируйте данные" - это в том числе делаю. и вроде всё работает, кроме одного момента - там, где есть List бывает срабатывает исключение при одновременной попытке обновления списка и с другой стороны попытка чтения из него. вот прямо сейчас изучаю варианты решения проблемы.

"вдруг в тему как пример" - а это нормально, обработчик маршрута представлять именно как таску?
